# How do I import CSV to Pandas df where data is organized by an index column with a parent/child relationship?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, ordereddict

**I have GBs of data in this text format:**

```
1,'Acct01','Freds Autoshop'   
2,'3-way-Cntrl','Y'   
1000,576,686,837   
1001,683,170,775   
1,'Acct02','Daves Tacos'   
2,'centrifugal','N'   
1000,334,787,143   
1001,749,132,987
```

The first column indicates the row content and is an index series that repeats for each Account (Acct01, Acct02...). Rows with index values (1,2) are one-to-one associated with each account (Parent). I would like to flatten this data into a dataframe that associates the Account level data (index = 1,2) with it's associated series data (1000, 10001, 1002, 1003...) the child data in a flat df.

**Desired df:**

```
'Acct01','Freds Autoshop','3-way-Cntrl','Y',1000,576,686,837   
'Acct01','Freds Autoshop','3-way-Cntrl','Y',1001,683,170,775   
'Acct02','Daves Tacos',2,'centrifugal','N',1000,334,787,143   
'Acct02','Daves Tacos',2,'centrifugal','N',1001,749,132,987
```

I've been able to do this in a very mechanical, very slow row-by-row process:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

file = 'C:\\PythonData\\AcctData.txt'

t0 = time.time()

pdata = [] # Parse data
acct = []  # Account Data
row = {}   #Assembly Container

#Set dataframe columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Account','Name','Type','Flag','Counter','CNT01','CNT02','CNT03'])

# open the file and read through it line by line
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        #Strip each line
        pdata = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]

        #Use the index to parse data into either acct[] for use on the rows with counter > 2
        indx = int(pdata[0])

        if indx == 1:
            acct.clear()
            acct.append(pdata[1])
            acct.append(pdata[2])
        elif indx == 2:
            acct.append(pdata[1])
            acct.append(pdata[2])
        else:
            row.clear()
            row['Account'] = acct[0]
            row['Name'] = acct[1]
            row['Type'] = acct[2]
            row['Flag'] = acct[3]
            row['Counter'] = pdata[0]
            row['CNT01'] = pdata[1]
            row['CNT02'] = pdata[2]
            row['CNT03'] = pdata[3]

        if indx > 2:
            #data.append(row)
            df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

t1 = time.time()

totalTimeDf = t1-t0

TTDf = '%.3f'%(totalTimeDf)
print(TTDf + " Seconds to Complete df: " + i_filepath)

print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
0.018 Seconds to Complete df: C:\PythonData\AcctData.txt   
    Account              Name             Type Flag Counter CNT01 CNT02 CNT03   
0  'Acct01'  'Freds Autoshop'    '3-way-Cntrl'  'Y'    1000   576   686   837   
1  'Acct01'  'Freds Autoshop'    '3-way-Cntrl'  'Y'    1001   683   170   775   
2  'Acct02'     'Daves Tacos'  'centrifugal'  'N'    1000   334   787   143   
3  'Acct02'     'Daves Tacos'  'centrifugal'  'N'    1001   749   132   987
```

This works but is tragically slow.  I suspect there is a very easy pythonic way to import and organize to a df.  It appears an OrderDict will properly organize the data as follows:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()

file_name = 'C:\\PythonData\\AcctData.txt'
try:
    csvfile = open(file_name, 'rt')
except:
    print("File not found")
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

for row in csvReader:
    key = row[0]
    od.setdefault(key,[]).append(row)   
od
```

**Result:**

```
OrderedDict([('1',   
[['1', "'Acct01'", "'Freds Autoshop'"],   
['1', "'Acct02'", "'Daves Tacos'"]]),   
('2',   
[['2', "'3-way-Cntrl'", "'Y'"],   
['2', "'centrifugal'", "'N'"]]),   
('1000',   
[['1000', '576', '686', '837'], ['1000', '334', '787', '143']]),   
('1001',   
[['1001', '683', '170', '775'], ['1001', '749', '132', '987']])])
```

From the OrderDict I haven't been able to figure out how to combine keys 1,2 and associate with acct specific series of keys (1000, 1001) then append into a df.  How do I go from OrderedDict to df while flattening the Parent/Child data?  Or, is there a better way to process this data?

Comment: Hi, is the provided text format correct? Considering each line is a row, the index (first columns) would be `1, 2, 1000, 1001, 1, 2, 1000, 1001`.

Comment: Correct.  Each line is a row.  The index (1,2,1000,1001) repeats for each account.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Each index 1,2 pair (an "Account") can have a variable number of data series (1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004).  For example, one account can have two series while another has 96 series.  Each account will have at least one data series but no more than 9999.  Also, I've oversimplified the data example.  In reality the data series rows (index value >= 1000) have a fixed number of columns but the columns are more like 80 plus 1 for the index value (many more than the four in my simple example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the fastes or the pythonic way, but I believe a pandas aproach might do, since you need to iterate for every 4 rows in a weird real specific way:

first importing libraries to work with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

since I didn't have a file to load, I just recreated it as an array (**this part you'll have to do some work, or simply load it to a pandas' DataFrame with 4 columns will be fine [like next step]**):

```
data = [[1,'Acct01','Freds Autoshop'],   
[2,'3-way-Cntrl','Y'  ], 
[1000,576,686,837   ],
[1001,683,170,775   ],
[1002,333,44,885   ],
[1003,611183,12,1   ],
[1,'Acct02','Daves Tacos'   ],
[2,'centrifugal','N'   ],
[1000,334,787,143  ] ,
[1001,749,132,987],
[1,'Acct03','Norah Jones'   ],
[2,'undertaker','N'   ],
[1000,323,1,3  ] ,
[1001,311,2,111  ] ,
[1002,95,112,4]]
```

**Created a dataframe with the above data** + created new columns with numpy's nans (faster than panda's) as placeholders.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['4']= np.nan
df['5']= np.nan
df['6']= np.nan
df['7']= np.nan
df['8']= np.nan
df.columns = ['idx','Account','Name','Type','Flag','Counter','CNT01','CNT02','CNT3']
```

Making a new df that will get everytime "AcctXXXX" apears and how many rows bellow until the next parent.

```
# Getting the unique "Acct" and their index position into an array
acct_idx_pos = np.array([df[df['Account'].str.contains('Acct').fillna(False)]['Account'].values, df[df['Account'].str.contains('Acct').fillna(False)].index.values])

# Making a df with the transposed array
df_pos = pd.DataFrame(acct_idx_pos.T, columns=['Acct', 'Position'])

# Shifting the values into a new column and filling the last value (nan) with the df length
df_pos['End_position'] = df_pos['Position'].shift(-1)
df_pos['End_position'][-1:] = len(df)

# Making the column we want, that is the number of loops we'll go
df_pos['Position_length'] = df_pos['End_position'] - df_pos['Position']
```

A custom function that uses a dummy Dataframe and concatenates temporary ones (will be used later)

```
def concatenate_loop_dfs(df_temp, df_full, axis=0):
    """
    to avoid retyping the same line of code for every df.
    the parameters should be the temporary df created at each loop and the concatenated DF that will contain all
    values which must first be initialized (outside the loop) as df_name = pd.DataFrame(). """      

    if df_full.empty:
        df_full = df_temp
    else:
        df_full = pd.concat([df_full, df_temp], axis=axis)

    return df_full
```

Created a **function that will loop to fill each row** and drop duplicated rows:

```
# a complicated loop function
def shorthen_df(df, num_iterations):

    # to not delete original df
    dataframe = df.copy()

    # for the slicing, we need to start at the first row.
    curr_row = 1

    # fill current row's nan values with values from next row
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,3] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row:curr_row+1:,1].values
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,4] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row:curr_row+1:,2].values
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,5] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+1:curr_row+2:,0].values
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,6] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+1:curr_row+2:,1].values
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,7] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+1:curr_row+2:,2].values
    dataframe.iloc[curr_row-1:curr_row:,8] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+1:curr_row+2:,3].values

    # the "num_iterations-2" is because the first two lines are filled and not replaced 
    # as the next ones will be. So this will vary correctly to each "account"
    for i in range(1, num_iterations-2):
        # Replaces next row with values from previous row
        dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-1):curr_row+i:] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-2):curr_row+(i-1):].values
        dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-1):curr_row+i:,5] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+i+1:curr_row+i+2:,0].values
        dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-1):curr_row+i:,6] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+i+1:curr_row+i+2:,1].values
        dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-1):curr_row+i:,7] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+i+1:curr_row+i+2:,2].values
        dataframe.iloc[curr_row+(i-1):curr_row+i:,8] = dataframe.iloc[curr_row+i+1:curr_row+i+2:,3].values

    # last 2 rows of df
    dataframe = dataframe[0:len(dataframe)-2]

    return dataframe
```

**Finally**, creating the dummy DF that will concat all "Acct" and loop for each one with it's position, using both functions above.

```
df_final= pd.DataFrame()
for start, end, iterations in zip(df_pos.Position.values, df_pos.End_position.values, df_pos.Position_length.values):
    df2 = df[start:end]

    df_temp = shorthen_df(df2, iterations)

    df_final = concatenate_loop_dfs(df_temp, df_final)

# Dropping first/unnecessary columns
df_final.drop('idx', axis=1, inplace=True)


# resetting index
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_final
```

**returns**

```
    Account Name    Type    Flag    Counter CNT01   CNT02   CNT3
0   Acct01  Freds Autoshop  3-way-Cntrl Y   1000.0  576 686 837
1   Acct01  Freds Autoshop  3-way-Cntrl Y   1001.0  683 170 775
2   Acct01  Freds Autoshop  3-way-Cntrl Y   1002.0  333 44  885
3   Acct01  Freds Autoshop  3-way-Cntrl Y   1003.0  611183  12  1
4   Acct02  Daves Tacos centrifugal N   1000.0  334 787 143
5   Acct02  Daves Tacos centrifugal N   1001.0  749 132 987
6   Acct03  Norah Jones undertaker  N   1000.0  323 1   3
7   Acct03  Norah Jones undertaker  N   1001.0  311 2   111
8   Acct03  Norah Jones undertaker  N   1002.0  95  112 4
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have made it clearer that each account can have a variable number of series (1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004...).  It was just implied in the text but I could have made that clearer.  Therefore, len(df)/4 is problematic.

Comment: I think I know what to change, I'm building it right now and I believe I'll post as another answer to be clearer.